# Running container on host network inside WSL2 does not open port

Tags: docker, networking, wsl-2

I am running nginx docker container in wsl2:

```
docker run --network host --name nginx-on-host -d nginx:1.23.2-alpine
```

I suppose that it should open 80 port (since default nginx port is 80) as it does when I run this command in raw Ubuntu + Docker, but it does not open 80 port.

I checked opend ports on wsl2 as well as on Windows host.

Wsl2:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

Cmd:

```
netstat -aon |  find /I "LISTENING"
```

Any ideas why is it so?

Comment: Are you using Docker Desktop?  Host networking silently doesn't work there, and it's unnecessary in any case.  Does the `docker run -p` option without `--network host` work better?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm trying to deploy redis cluster locally in wsl2. It is said in the redis documentation (https://redis.io/docs/management/scaling/)  that network must be set to `host` : `To make Docker compatible with Redis Cluster, you need to use Docker's host networking mode`